# Much ajax website puts down godaddy

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a search made ​​with ajax and an input tag with onkeyup:

```
function BuscarNitServ() {
  var str = "nit=" + $("#empresa").val();
  $("#BusquedaNitServ").fadeIn();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'BuscarNitServ.php',
    data: str,
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#BusquedaNitServ").html(msg)
    }
  });
}
```

html:

```
<input type='text' name='empresa' id='empresa' onkeyup="BuscarNitServ()" onblur="QuitarNitServ()" size='50' />
```

but apparently called many times the ajax puts down momentarily connection godaddy website .

This happens all the hosting or only be goddady ?

Comment: You might consider using a timeout to only send the Ajax request after the user has paused typing, to reduce load.

Comment: Also, remember that these calls are asynchronous, and you're not throwing away old ones when you make a new one. So it's quite possible that the end result is not the result from the last call that was sent.